# Emotion Js and TypeScript problems when passing props to styled

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

i got this errors:

```
No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(...styles: Interpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>'.
      Type 'TemplateStringsArray' is not assignable to type 'ObjectInterpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>'.
        Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
          Type '{ <S extends string>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | undefined'.
            Type '{ <S extends string>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: readonly string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): string[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.   Overload 2 of 2, '(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...styles: Interpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(props: HamburguerProps) => "250px" | "0"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>'.
      Type '(props: HamburguerProps) => "250px" | "0"' is not assignable to type 'FunctionInterpolation<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'mergedProps' are incompatible.
          Property 'open' is missing in type 'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | ... 264 more ... | "value"> & { ...; }' but required in type 'HamburguerProps'.  TS2769
```

on this code:

```
> 25 | export const Hamburguer = styled('button')`
       |                           ^
    26 |   position: absolute;
    27 |   left: ${(props: HamburguerProps) => (props.open ? '250px' : '0')};
    28 | `;
```

I was thinking that the problem was related to my code, but doing all the tests, I believe it is not that

I looked for this error or solutions and I didn't find

my **TsConfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node", "@emotion/core"],
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**my Tsx code:**

```
import Logo from 'assets/images/Logo.png';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleSide } from 'redux/slices/sideBar';

interface RootState {
  sideBarStatus: boolean;
}

interface SideBar {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

const LogoNavigation: React.FC<SideBar> = ({ isOpen }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <LogoSide>
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo Elo Ghost" />
      <Hamburguer open={isOpen} onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSide(!isOpen))}>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div />
      </Hamburguer>
    </LogoSide>
  );
};

const SideNavigation: React.FC = () => {
  // const { sideIsOpen } = useSelector((RootState) => RootState.toggleSide);
  const selectIsOpen = (state: RootState) => state.sideBarStatus;
  const sideBarStatus = useSelector(selectIsOpen);
  return (
    <SideNav>
      <LogoNavigation isOpen={sideBarStatus} />
    </SideNav>
  );
};

export default SideNavigation;
```

**My Styles with emotion**

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

type HamburguerProps = {
  open: boolean;
};

export const SideNav = styled('nav')`
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #437fb9;
`;

export const LogoSide = styled('div')`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #fdca40;
  img {
    height: 50px;
  }
`;

export const Hamburguer = styled('button')`
  position: absolute;
  left: ${(props: HamburguerProps) => (props.open ? '250px' : '0')};
`;
```

and here I have a gif where I render my component, but right after the error appears

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with JSS libraries (such as Emotion and Styled Components) and TypeScript, to make the `props` work, you will have to provide the generics which specifies the typings. This can be done with the use of interfaces or type aliases.

For your case, you will need to specific that Hamburger has the `HamburguerProps` by using `styled<HamburguerProps>`:

```
export const Hamburguer = styled.button<HamburguerProps>`
  position: absolute;
  left: ${(props) => (props.open ? '250px' : '0')};
`;
```

Comment: hiii i got this error with this: Type 'HamburguerProps' does not satisfy the constraint '"symbol" | "object" | "nav" | "a" | "abbr" | "address" | "area" | "article" | "aside" | "audio" | "b" | "base" | "bdi" | "bdo" | "big" | "blockquote" | "body" | "br" | "button" | "canvas" | ... 154 more ... | "view"'.
  Type 'HamburguerProps' is not assignable to type '"view"'

Comment: styled.button<HamburguerProps>` this work thank u alot brother.

Comment: can help me here bro? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427095/emotion-js-hamburger-animation

Comment: for some reason my animation that works based on my state is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to [extend the styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) of an existing component (using `styled-components` or `@emotion/styled`), the syntax will be slightly different. For example, if we have a `BaseButton` that we're trying to extend:

```
interface BaseButtonProps {
  color: string
}

const BaseButton = styled.button<BaseButtonProps>`
  ${props => {
    if (props.color === 'red') {
      return `
        color: red;
      `;
    }

    return `
      color: green;
    `;
  }}
`;

...

interface HamburguerProps extends BaseButtonProps {
  open: boolean
}

export const Hamburguer = styled(BaseButton)<HamburguerProps>`
  position: absolute;
  left: ${(props) => (props.open ? '250px' : '0')};
`;
```

Make sure you put the `HamburguerProps` interface argument to the RIGHT side

```
styled(BaseButton)<HamburguerProps>
```

and NOT the LEFT side

```
styled<HamburguerProps>(BaseButton)
```